# Table in a header using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I am working with Python and Word application. I am trying to generate a table in the header of every page.

I tried this :

```
word.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(win32com.client.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1)
word.ActiveDocument.Save()
```

but without success.

Comment: Have you tried adding something simpler, like text?